# Uploadifive & Codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter-2, uploadify

I have the following in my view file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/uploadifive.css">
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/uploadify/jquery.uploadifive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/uploadify/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
```

then i have:

```
<div id="queue"></div>
            <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true"  class="uploadifive-button">
            <a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
            <!-- Uploadify stuff-->

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $timestamp = time(); ?>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
    'auto'             : true,
    'checkScript'      : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/check_image',
    'formData'         : {
                 'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                 'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                         },
    'queueID'          : 'queue',
    'uploadScript'     : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/uploadi',
    'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
  });
 });
```

which is in the sample but yet the button isn't like the sample and nothing works no errors no uploading no nothing, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Put jquery.min.js before jquery.uploadifive.min.js and try again

Like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/uploadifive.css">
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/uploadify/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/uploadify/jquery.uploadifive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm. i haven't been using uplodifive (only the uploadify :D ).

as i see in their implementation this is the code (basically same as uploadify :) )

```
<form>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>
```

also, as Dshah mention, you definitely need to put jquery.js before uploadifive.js